# Как получить данные профиля Overwatch?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу вывести `level` и `prestige` аккаунта Overwatch на `python`. Как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можете использовать неофициальную [api](https://ow-api.com/docs/) для overwatch

Вот пример запроса:

```
import requests
response = requests.get(f"https://ow-api.com/v2/stats/pc/{battletag.replace('#', '-')}/complete")
print(response.json())
```